# Switch from a UiviewController to a UiNavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

in my application the user has to sign in. If the user hasn't previously signed in that the AppDelageate will take the user to a UiviewController where they can then login. If they have previously logedin than the user is brought to a UiNavigationController. The problem I am having is that ounce he user signs in correctly I cant figure out how to bring them to the UinavigationController. The times I did successfully transition the Uinavigation bar wouldn't show up and was having a null value.

I probably should note that the UinavigationController I have been talking about is a UiviewController with a UinavigationController Embedded in it.

Comment: Hmm...a UIViewController with a UINavigationController embedded in it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this in my apps is to have the login screen be presented modaly instead of part of the stack. So have the main screen be a navigation controller and when it loads, check to see if the user is not logged in, and if they are not logged in, present the login screen.